# Cool pack failure, no response from accel

Tags: coil-on-plug

I had the front differential changed at Big o tires and got it back running like crap, the throttle body light is on now ( lightning symbol ) so we changed the throttle body and the accelerator and its still running the same, idling high and the whole left side coil ain’t responding when u unplug it when it’s running but right side is responding..Need help on what it is???

The throttle plate has no response when pressed manually and the accelerator has barely any response, from 1000 rpm to 1500 rpm when floored. All fuses were checked and a smoke test was also completed to check for leaks with no leaks found.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please help us out here a little bit? You don't give us any vehicle information. Without it, we can't even start to give you advice.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.